# Replacing old, scribbly panel directory labeling

Tags: electrical-panel

I purchased an older home built in 1975.  It has a GE Powermark Gold panel box with 150 amp service.  The home has been remodeled a few times, so the panel box label for the breakers have been marked thru numerous times and is quite confusing to read at a glance.  Between the home inspection and electrician visits, I’ve got it figured out what does what, but is there somewhere I can purchase a new master label so that it will be clear and easy to read in an emergency?

Comment: in an emergency, flip the main breaker ... do not rely on  flipping the correct breaker, no matter how well it is labeled

Comment: Shopping questions are considered off-topic at least partially due to changing market availability, so the TU goes to George, but if you stroll down the isle at your local big box hardware depot you might find close to what you for, a generic directory with sleeve https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-Load-Center-Circuit-Directory-2-Pack-CKTDIR/205543639

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do that. I usually just create a MS-Word or Excel document with a "table" identifying the breakers by number and what they serve.  Then print it and tape it to the inside of the door to the panel. If you want, you could go to an office supply store and get some full page sticky paper. Either works well. Glad you figured out what goes where.

Comment: This panel schedule says "Eaton", but you can ignore that https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://www.moeller.ca/ecm/groups/public/@pub/@eatonca/@elec/documents/content/pct_1168773.xls Opens in read-only mode, save and re-open, select single phase tab at bottom.